# Looking for a MacOS equivalent for command: konsole -e "docker-compose up"

Tags: macos, fedora

Anyone knows what should be the MacOS equivalent for the following command ?

```
konsole -e "docker-compose up"
```

the command works in Fedora, but I cannot find a way to run it in MacOS. I've tried to install konsole, but after installing it using this method (https://ports.macports.org/port/konsole/) it doesn't seem to work. konsole doesn't get installed.

I've also tried : `open -n -a Terminal`  but this approach doesn't offer a way to pass a command and execute it in the new Terminal window.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can test this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
run-command(){
    local tmp=$(mktemp) 
    echo $'#!/bin/bash\n'"rm $tmp; cd ${PWD@Q}; clear; ${@@Q}" > $tmp
    chmod 755 $tmp ; open -a Terminal $tmp
} 
run-command sleep 5
```

If everything is fine, then

```
run-command docker-compose up
```